# Special Characters Parsing in ios

Tags: ios

I am having a problem with getting actual parsing Data in XMLParser. After UrlConnection Delegates, at Did receive Data (if I converted it to string) I get the following strings:

```
<folder>
    <id>5</id>
    <name> DEEPAK  </name>
    <mobile>123456</mobile>
    <email>dee@company.com</email>
    <address>dee address</address>
    <designation>VICE PRESIDENT â A</designation>
    <working_period>2 years</working_period>
</folder>
```

and finally after parsing it I get the Data string below:

```
{
    address = "dee address";
    designation = "\U2013 A";
    email = "dee@company.com";
    id = 5;
    mobile = 123456;
    name = "DEEPAK  ";
}
```

Now I am confused that the designation Was not coming properly (i.e. isn't actual string). Instead of

```
<designation>VICE PRESIDENT â A</designation>
```

I am getting only string: designation = "\U2013 A";

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct string encoding?

Comment: Yes Iam Sure That When I get the string from XML, it is seperated

Comment: Like instead EXECUTIVE VICE PRESIDENT â A  Iam getting only A

Comment: Show the line of code you use to turn the data into a string. You should probably be using `initWithData:encoding:` what do you pass for  the encoding parameter, and are you certain that the encoding you pass to that method is the same encoding used for the data?